# UINavigationController - JTRevealSidebar

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem which is in JTRevealSiderbar's Sidebarviewcontroller , where sidebar button pressed delegate i am calling a code like :

```
OpeningViewController *controller = [[OpeningViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//controller.title = (NSString *)object;
controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
controller.leftSelectedIndexPath      = indexPath;
sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:controller, nil];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllerArray];
```

i have checked that from the baseviewcontroller , siderbarviewcontroller and my openingviewcontroller , uinavigationcontroller's memory address is the same.

besides , when i call the code above , OpeningViewController's viewdid load and appear also called without problem.

but here's my problem , view is not shown !? i could not figure out why is this problem.

i have checked that self.navigationController's viewControllers property is null? maybe this is the problem but i also could not figure out why navigationcontroller's viewcontrollers are empty?

someone help me please , any thought will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i am using storyboard and segues , i have created a viewid for my storyboard for each of the viewcontrollers and create each viewcontroller with their storyboard ids . when i implemented this i just needed to give a background image to my each viewcontroller (still i do not know why this happened) . but this solved my problem totally.

if you need any help about this , you can comment on this then i'll pass some codes.